# Need to get issuelinks types with Jira python

Tags: jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am writing a script with Jira python and I have encountered a big obstacle here.

I need to access to one of the issuelinks under "is duplicated by" but I don't have any idea about the attributes I can use.

I can get to the issuelinks field but I can't go further from here.

This is I've got so far:

```
issue = jira.issue(ISSUE_NUM) #this is the issue I am handling

link = issue.fields.issuelinks # I 've accessed to the issuelinks field

if hasattr(link, "inwardIssue"):

    inwardIssue = link.inwardIssue
```

and I want to do this from here :

```
if(str(inwardIssue.type(?)) == "is duplicated by"):
```

inward Issues can be

- is cloned by
- is duplicated by

and so on.

how can I get the type of inward Issues??

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a few types of issue links. So far I've seen: `Blocker`, `Cause`, `Duplicate` and `Reference`.

In order to identify the *type* that the IssueLink is you can do the following:

```py
issue = jira.issue(ISSUE_NUM)

all_issue_links = issue.fields.issuelinks

for link in all_issue_links:
    if link.type.name == 'Duplicate':
        inward_issue = link.inwardIssue
        # Do something with link
```